# How to perform str.strip in dataframe and save it with inplace=true?

Tags: python, dataframe, strip

I have dataframe with n columns. And I want to perform a strip to strings in one of the columns in the dataframe. I was able to do it, but I want this change to reflect in the original dataframe.

Dataframe: data

```
         Name

0        210123278414410005
1        101232784144610006
2        210123278414410007
3        21012-27841-410008
4        210123278414410009



After stripping:

         Name
0        10005
1        10006
2        10007
3        10008
4        10009
5        10010
```

I tried the below code and strip was successful

```
data['Name'].str.strip().str[13:]
```

However if I check dataframe, the strip is not reflected.

I am looking for something like inplace parameter.

Comment: Why not just do `data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip().str[13:]`?

Answer (score 3):

String methods (the attributes of the `.str` attribute on a series) will only ever return a new Series, you can't use these for in-place changes. Your only option is to assign it back to the same column:

```
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip().str[13:]
```

You could instead use the [`Series.replace()` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with a regular expression, and `inplace=True`:

```
data['Name'].replace(r'(?s)\A\s*(.{,13}).*(?<!\s)\s*\Z', r'\1', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The regular expression above matches up to 13 characters after leading whitespace, and ignores trailing whitespace and any other characters beyond the first 13 after whitespace is removed. It produces the same output as `.str.strip().str[:13]`, but makes the changes in place.

The pattern is using a negative look-behind to make sure that the final `\s*` pattern matches all whitespace elements at the end before selecting between 0 and 13 characters of what remains. The `\A` and `\Z` anchors make it so the whole string is matched, and the `(?s)` at the start switches the `.` pattern (dot, any character except newlines) to include newlines when matching; this way an input value like `'    foo\nbar   '` is handled correctly.

Put differently, the `\A\s*` and `(?<!\s)\s*\Z` patterns act like `str.strip()` does, matching all whitespace at the start and end, respectively, and no more. The `(.{,13)).*` pattern matches everything in between, with the first 13 characters of those (or fewer, if there are not enough characters to match after stripping) captured as a group. That one group is then used as the replacement value.

And because `.` doesn't normally match `\n` characters, the `(?s)` flag at the start tells the regex engine to match newline characters anyway. We want *all* characters to be included after stripping, not just all except one.

Comment: [inplace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) is not there.

Comment: @prosti: no, because it [is here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html). You linked to `Series.str.replace()`, not `Series.replace()`. Note the difference between the two, you are looking at the *string method*, not the Series method.

Answer (score 1):

`data['Name'].str.strip().str[13:]` returns you the new transformed column, but it is not changing in-place data (inside the dataframe). You should write:

`data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip().str[13:]`

to write the transformed data to the `Name` column.

Comment: thanks , I was doing this only. But thought, it might have a parameter like inplace. This works anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers that there's no inplace parameter for the strip function, as seen in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for `str.strip`.

To add to that: I've found the `str` functions for pandas Series usually used when selecting specific rows. Like `df[df['Name'].str.contains('69')`. I'd say this is a possible reason that it doesn't have an inplace parameter -- it's not meant to be completely "stand-alone" like `rename` or `drop`.

Also to add! I think a more pythonic solution is to use negative indices instead:

```
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip().str[-5:]
```

This way, we don't have to assume that there are 18 characters, and/or we'll consistently get "last 5 characters" instead!

Answer (score 0):

As per yatu's comment: you should reassign the Series with stripped values to the original column.

```
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip().str[13:]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to note that pandas DataFrames do work on `numpy` beneath.
There is also the idea to do broadcasting operations in `numpy`.

Here is the example I had in mind:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['210123278414410005', '101232784144610006']])
dfn=df.to_numpy(copy=False) #numpy array
df=pd.DataFrame(np.frompyfunc(lambda dfn: dfn[13:],1,1)(dfn) )

print(df) #10005  10006
```

This doesn't answer your question but it is just another option (it creates a new datafram from the numpy array though).

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'apply' function

```
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda e: str(e)[13:]
```