# .strip() with in-place solution not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a solution for stripping blank spaces from some strings in my DataFrame. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041043/how-to-perform-str-strip-in-dataframe-and-save-it-with-inplace-true/56041084#56041084?newreg=c47152b157c24981a3e214a7bc0446a1), where someone said this:

> I agree with the other answers that there's no inplace parameter for
> the strip function, as seen in [the
> documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)
> for `str.strip`.
>
> To add to that: I've found the `str` functions for pandas Series
> usually used when selecting specific rows. Like
> `df[df['Name'].str.contains('69')`. I'd say this is a possible reason
> that it doesn't have an inplace parameter -- it's not meant to be
> completely "stand-alone" like `rename`  or `drop`.
>
> Also to add! I think a more pythonic solution is to use negative
> indices instead:
>
> `data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip().str[-5:]`
>
> This way, we don't have to assume that there are 18 characters, and/or
> we'll consistently get "last 5 characters" instead!

So, I have a list of DataFrames called 'dataframes'. On the first dataframe (which is dataframes[0]), I have a column named 'CNJ' with string values, some of them with a blank space in the end. For example:

Input:

```
dataframes[0]['cnj'][9]
```

Output:

```
'0100758-73.2019.5.01.0064 '
```

So, following the comment above, I did this:

Input:

```
dataframes[0]['cnj'] = dataframes[0]['cnj'].strip()
```

Then I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Since the solution given on the other topic worked, what am I doing wrong to get this error? It seemed to me it shouldn't work because its a Series, but it should get the same result as the one mentioned above (`data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip().str[-5:]`), right?

Comment: Oh, and I tried with the .str. as well, but I got the following error:

Ok. Forget. Now it worked. Now I need your help to delete this question '-_-

Comment: A Series object has no `strip`. Use `str.strip`. If you got an error with that post *that* error. The code from the other solution *does* use `str`: `data['Name'].str.strip()`. That returns a new Series, which is why `.str[-5]` is used (PS: I always get that wrong. I only remember to add `str` again after I get an error)

Comment: Have you tried `dataframes[0]['cnj'].str.strip()`? if `dataframes[0]` returns a DataFrame then `dataframes[0]['cnj']` will return a Series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
dataframes[0]['cnj']=dataframes[0]['cnj'].str.strip()
```

or better yet, store the dataframe in a variable first:

```
df0=dataframes[0]
df0['cnj']=df0['cnj'].str.strip()
```

---

The code in the solution you posted uses `.str`. :

```
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.strip().str[-5:]
```

The Pandas Series object has no string or date manipulation methods methods. These are exposed through the [Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) and [Series.dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) accessor objects.

The result of [Series.str.strip()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) is a new series. That's why `.str[-5:]` is needed to retrieve the last 5 characters. That results is a new series again. That expression is equivalent to :

```
temp_series=data['Name'].str.strip()
data['Name'] = temp_series.str[-5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply a transformation function on the column values like this.

```
data["Name"] = data["Name"].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip()[-5:])
```

Comment: Why? [pandas.Series.str.strip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) isn't broken.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a string without the right spaces is a series or a dataframe right, at least that's my understanding looking at your query, use `str.rstrip()` which will work both on **series** and **dataframe** objects.

**Note:** `strip()` usually is only for **string datatypes**, so the error you are getting is appropriate.

Refer to [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) , and try implementing `str.rstrip()` provided by pandas.

For `str.strip()` you can refer to this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), it works for me.

In your case, assuming the `dataframe` column to be `s`, you can use the below code:

```
df[s].str.strip()
```

Comment: Series has no `rstrip` or any other string method. You have to use `str.` to get to the string methods. `str.strip` and `str.rstrip` are both valid

Comment: Actually I need strings with no spaces. This one was an example, but I also have strings with left spaces. Anyway, I guess I could solve it with the .str. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NataliaM. the code you posted uses `str`. You didn't use that code, you used something different.

Comment: I have modified the answer go ahead and try the suggestion from the official documentation, if the error still persists comment here.